# Docker - Unable to write to a mounted volume

Tags: docker, airflow, user-permissions

I am trying to write a file and end up with the permission denied error. My current user isn't root and it is the user "airflow" (UID:50000) that the airflow docker image creates.

I have been able to figure out everything else other than how to write to a mounted drive.
Below is the way I have mounted the file in my docker file.

```
volumes:
    - model:/usr/local/airflow/model:rw

model:
          driver: local
          driver_opts:
              type: cifs
              o: username=${USER},password=${PASSWORD},domain=xx
              device: "\\\\1X.XX.XX.XX\\Drive$$"
```

Also I am using docker for windows. How do I give permissions to the user to write a file?

Comment: Do you have the right to write on this model as your current user ? Can you show the rights access of this folder please ?

Comment: Yes. The account we are using to write to the volume does have permissions to read/write on the folder.

Answer (score 0):

For airflow, this is what I did that works.

1. Remove volume creation and mount from docker-compose.yml
2. Run the `docker compose up`
3. Find the id of the container `docker ps -aqf "name=airflow-airflow-worker"`
4. Mount from root user

> docker exec -u root -it [id_from_above] mount -t cifs -o domain=CORP,username=[windows_username_without@],password=[windows_password],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,uid=50000,gid=0,vers=3.0,serverino,rw //IP.IP.IP.IP/path /mnt/q